# Why is dispatch_sync on custom concurrent queue deadlocking

Tags: objective-c, ios, grand-central-dispatch

I'm seeing an intermittent deadlock in my app when using dispatch_sync on a custom concurrent dispatch_queue. I'm using something similar to the method described in [Mike Ash's blog](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-10-14-whats-new-in-gcd.html) to support concurrent read access but threadsafe mutations on an NSMutableDictionary that acts as a cache of currently active network RPC requests. My project uses ARC.

I create the queue with:

```
dispatch_queue_t activeRequestsQueue = dispatch_queue_create("my.queue.name",
                                                DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
```

and the mutable dictionary with

```
NSMutableDictionary *activeRequests = [[NSMutable dictionary alloc] init];
```

I read elements from the queue like this:

```
- (id)activeRequestForRpc: (RpcRequest *)rpc
{
    assert(![NSThread isMainThread]);
    NSString * key = [rpc getKey];
    __block id obj = nil;
    dispatch_sync(activeRequestsQueue, ^{
        obj = [activeRequests objectForKey: key];
    });
    return obj;
}
```

I add and remove rpcs from the cache

```
- (void)addActiveRequest: (RpcRequest *)rpc
{
    NSString * key = [rpc getKey];
    dispatch_barrier_async(activeRequestsQueue, ^{
        [activeRequests setObject: rpc forKey: key];
    });
}

- (void)removeActiveRequest: (RpcRequest *)rpc
{
    NSString * key = [rpc getKey];
    dispatch_barrier_async(activeRequestsQueue, ^{
        [activeRequests removeObjectForKey:key];
    });
}
```

I'm seeing the deadlock in the call to activeRequestForRpc when I make a lot of network requests at once which leads me to believe that one of the barrier blocks (add or remove) is not completing execution. I always call activeRequestForRpc from a background thread, and the app UI doesn't freeze so I don't think it has to do blocking the main thread, but I added the assert statement just in case. Any ideas on how this deadlock could be happening?

**UPDATE: adding code that is calling these methods**

I'm using AFNetworking to make the network requests and I have an NSOperationQueue that I'm scheduling the 'check cache and maybe fetch resource from network' logic. I'll call that op the CheckCacheAndFetchFromNetworkOp. Inside that op I make a call out to my custom subclass of AFHTTPClient to make an RPC request.

```
// this is called from inside an NSOperation executing on an NSOperationQueue.
- (void) enqueueOperation: (MY_AFHTTPRequestOperation *) op {
    NSError *error = nil;
    if ([self activeRequestForRpc:op.netRequest.rpcRequest]) {
        error = [NSError errorWithDomain:kHttpRpcErrorDomain code:HttpRpcErrorDuplicate userInfo:nil];
    }
    // set the error on the op and cancels it so dependent ops can continue.
    [op setHttpRpcError:error];

    // Maybe enqueue the op
    if (!error) {
        [self addActiveRequest:op.netRequest.rpcRequest];
        [self enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:op];
    }
}
```

The MY_AFHTTRequestOperation is built by the AFHTTPClient instance and inside both the success and failure completion blocks I call `[self removeActiveRequest:netRequest.rpcRequest];` as the first action. These blocks are executed on the main thread by AFNetworking as the default behavior.

I've seen the deadlock happen where the last barrier block that must be holding the lock on the queue is both the add block and the remove block.

Is it possible that as the system spawns more threads to support the CheckCacheAndFetchFromNetworkOp Ops in my NSOperationQueue, the activeRequestsQueue would be too low priority to get scheduled? That could cause deadlock if all threads were taken by CheckCacheAndFetchFromNetworkOps blocking to try and read from the activeRequests Dictionary, and the activeRequestsQueue was blocking on an add/remove barrier block that couldn't execute.

**UPDATE**

Fixed the issue by setting the NSOperationQueue to have maxConcurrentOperation count of 1 (or really anything reasonable other than the default NSOperationQueueDefaultMaxConcurrentOperationCount).

Basically the lesson I took away is that you shouldn't have an NSOperationQueue with the default max operation count wait on any other dispatch_queue_t or NSOperationQueue since it could potentially hog all threads from those other queues.

This is what was happening.

**queue** - NSOperationQueue set to default NSDefaultMaxOperationCount which lets system determine how many concurrent ops to run.

**op** - runs on queue1 and schedules a network request on the AFNetworking queue after reading to make sure the RPC isn't in the activeRequest set.

Here is the flow:

The system determines that it can support 10 concurrent threads (In reality it was more like 80).

10 ops get scheduled at once. The system lets 10 ops run concurrently on it's 10 threads. All 10 ops call hasActiveRequestForRPC which schedules a sync block on the activeRequestQueue and blocks the 10 threads. The activeRequestQueue wants to run it's read block, but doesn't have any available threads. At this point we already have a deadlock.

More commonly I would see something like 9 ops (1-9) get scheduled, one of them, op1, quickly runs a hasActiveRequestForRPC on the 10th thread and schedules an addActiveRequest barrer block. Then another op would get scheduled on the 10th thread and the op2-10 would schedule and wait on an hasActiveRequestForRPC. Then the op1's scheduled addRpc block wouldn't run since the op10 took up the last available thread, and all the other hasActiveRequestForRpc blocks would wait for the barrier block to execute. op1 would end up blocking later when it tried to schedule a cache operation on a different operation queue that also couldn't get access to any threads.

I was assuming that the blocking hasActiveRequestForRPC were waiting on a barrer block to execute, but the key was the activeRequestQueue waiting on **any** thread availability.

Comment: Does the getKey (you should have called it key) method protect the object with a mutex? If that's the case the problem is that in activeRequestForRpc: the mutex is always locked, and it doesn't terminate.

Comment: no it doesn't protect the object with a mutex since the rpcs are immutable and I didn't think it was needed. It's actually just calling another method in the same class that generates a key from an RPC, but I wrote it that way for simplicity. the implementation looks like this: methodSignature { return [NSSTringWithFormat, "string %@, %@..." rpc.someField...]; }

Comment: Is it possible that this method is being called from the same queue? make sure `dispatch_get_current_queue != activeRequestQueue`

Comment: I don't think it's possible since the only three blocks that ever get scheduled on activeRequestQueue are the ones shown in the question for read, remove, and add. I added an assert(dispatch_get_current_queue() != activeRequestsQueue); above the dispatch_sync call and I still see the freeze :(

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code that is calling these methods to debug this further.

Comment: Can you post stack traces of all active threads when this deadlock happens?

Comment: I don't think the deadlock you describe could happen, because if all threads were blocked waiting for that queue, the remaining barrier block would get time eventually.

Comment: First of all you should know, that when you create a barrier some of your thread will stop at the point of your barrier.

Comment: Trigger the deadlock.  Then, in Xcode, choose Product > Debug > Pause from the menu bar.  Then choose View > Navigators > Show Debug Navigator.  In the Debug Navigator (left panel of window), open the disclosure triangles for all of the threads.  Then click on the “Thread 1” line, and shift-click on the last frame of the last thread.  Choose Edit > Copy from the menu bar.  Edit your post and paste in the copied stack frames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Turns out the problem was that the NSOperationQueue which is calling `enqueueOperation:` is using all available threads, so since they are all waiting (via dispatch_sync) for something to happen on the `activeRequestsQueue`. Reducing the maxConcurrentOperations on this queue solved the problem (see comments), though this is not really a great solution because it makes assumptions about the number of cores, etc. A better solution would be to use `dispatch_async` rather than `dispatch_sync`, though this will make the code more complex.

My earlier suggestions:

- You're calling `dispatch_sync(activeRequestsQueue, ...)` when you're already on the activeRequestsQueue (and your assert isn't firing for some reason, like you're running in release.)
- `[activeRequests removeObjectForKey:key];` is causing a request to be deallocated, and the dealloc is waiting for something that calls `activeRequestForRpc:`, which would cause a deadlock.

Comment: 1. definitely running in debug - I made a simple test assert(NO) to verify that they do in fact trigger. Can't think of other ways I could be executing on activeRequestQueue since only place anything ever gets scheduled are in the methods posts.  

2. I'm using arc so haven't written any custom dealloc methods on my objects. I actually just changed the implementation to be a NSMutableSet instead of a dictionary so I'm just using the string key now. I'll try to get the stack traces together.

Comment: If you don't have dealloc, what about methods in RpcRequest like `isEqual:` or `hash`, which the dictionary could be calling in either barrier method?

Comment: changed to NSMutableSet so I'm just reading/writing/removing strings now, not RPCRequests. I still see the same behavior. Changing the priority of the queue makes the problem much less frequent (from 50% to about 10%), but I still see it `dispatch_set_target_queue(activeRequestsQueue, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0));`

Comment: Just had a thought. If your NSOperationQueue which is calling enqueueOperation: is using all available threads, perhaps that's what's deadlocking you. What is maxConcurrentOperations set to on that queue? Can you try setting it to 1 and see what happens?

Comment: I'll accept this answer if you change it to mention that I should change the maxConcurrentOperations on a queue to something else. I naively assumed that Apple's statement that the maximum would "change dynamically based on system conditions" would prevent this sort of thing.